# Question about Bases

Tags: linear-algebra

If I got a vector $v$ in  the canonical base, and I want to represent that vector in another base $B$ , but  the problem is that given base $B$ has less elements than the dimension  of the vector space. Can I add more elements  to the base $B$ ( keeping it linearly independent ) ?

Comment: Yes, you can extend $B$ into a set of up to $n$ linear independent vectors, assuming the large vector space is of dimension $n$.

Comment: Thanks. Can I add canonical vectors to $B$

Comment: Each vector you add should keep the set linear independent. So you need to check if the new vector is not already spaned by the existing set. And that is necessary for canonical vectors as well.